# path optimization (tsp) in python

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

I want to optimize the path of some gcode (for cnc machines). There could be tens of thousands of shapes, which are the "cities". It is effectively TSP except without the requirement to return to the initial city, and with the added complication that each "city" can have a different start and end point, as not all shapes are closed.

My brute force attempt looks for the closest city and goes to that, then removes that from the list and adds to a new list of optimized order. It searches both the start and end points of all remaining cities and in the case that the closest is an end point, reverses the order of that shape before adding to the new list. It works but is very slow.

Not searching for the absolute most optimal path, just best I can reasonably get. Can I optimize this method or is there an entirely better approach?

```
def getDistance(a, b):                      # calcs distance between two (x,y) tuples
    x1, y1 = a[0], a[1]
    x2, y2 = b[0], b[1]

    x = x2 - x1
    y = y2 - y1

    return sqrt(x * x + y * y)

# shapes is a list of lists (the shapes) of tuples (the (x,y) coords)  

newOrder = []
newOrder.append(shapes.pop(0))

while shapes:

    shortest = float("Inf")    
    last = newOrder[-1][-1]

    for shape in shapes:

        d = getDistance(last, shape[0])     # distance to start of shape
        d2 = getDistance(last,shape[-1])    # distance to end of shape

        if d < shortest:
            shortest = d
            selection = shape
            reverse = False

        if d2 < shortest:
            shortest = d2
            reverse = True                  # do the reverse later so I have the original shape to perform shapes.remove(selection)
            selection = shape

    if reverse:
        newOrder.append([x for x in reversed(selection)])
    else:
        newOrder.append(selection)
    shapes.remove(selection)
```

Comment: One simple *strength reduction* is to remove the sqrt in the distance calculation. This saves an expensive operation but keeps the Euclidean distance.

Comment: that made a pretty big difference! cheers

Comment: I feel like this can be optimized with numpy or so. Will take a look

Comment: Is each shape a sequence of 2-element tuples or so?

Comment: `[x for x in reversed(selection)]` is just `list(reversed(selection))`

Comment: Is each shape a sequence of 2-element tuples or so? - Yes